# Connecting to neo4j in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, neo4j

I tried to run a simple code connecting Neo4j with Java script, But I don't know why there isn't any change in database, I tried a verity type of connection. You can see the code in the following:

```
const neo4j = require('neo4j-driver')
//const driver = neo4j.driver("neo4j://localhost:7687", neo4j.auth.basic("neo4j", "qaz"));
 const driver = neo4j.driver("bolt://localhost:7687", neo4j.auth.basic("neo4j", "qaz"));

const session = driver.session()
const personName = 'Test'
try {
   const result =  session.run(
      'CREATE (a:Person {name: $name}) RETURN a',
      { name: personName }
   )

const singleRecord = result.records[0]
const node = singleRecord.get(0)

console.log(node.properties.name)
}
finally {
  session.close()
}
```

// on application exit:
driver.close()

Even I tried the online database, but I had the problem still. Also I couldn't receive any error or warning.  Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you try to catch errors and see what comes out.
The only problem I imagine seeing is that you use "neu4j" username instead of the "neo4j".

Anyway, the best practice is to catch errors to help you with the debugging.

// Edit:

It seems that you are not awaiting the results of the Neo4j session as JS is all about async :)
Try to use the `then` clause like in the documentation:

```
session
  .run('MERGE (james:Person {name : $nameParam}) RETURN james.name AS name', {
    nameParam: 'James'
  })
  .then(result => {
    result.records.forEach(record => {
      console.log(record.get('name'))
    })
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error)
  })
  .then(() => session.close())
```

Comment: No, That is right, it was just a typo mistake here. Actually there isn't any  errors for connection, but there is just a error when result.records[0] runs   " TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined"

Comment: No, there is the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found how to solve it

```
async function test(){
const neo4j = require('neo4j-driver')

const driver = neo4j.driver("bolt://localhost:7687", neo4j.auth.basic("neo4j", "qaz"))
const session = driver.session()
const personName = 'Test'

try {
    const result = await session.run(
        'CREATE (a:Person {name: $name}) RETURN a',
        { name: personName }
    )

    const singleRecord = result.records[0]
    const node = singleRecord.get(0)

    console.log(node.properties.name)
} finally {
    await session.close()
}

 // on application exit:
  await driver.close()
}
 test();
```